# Scroll horizontally in programmatically created ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm creating a ScrollView, nesting in a RelativeLayout (which contains tables). Everything is properly added to the layout. The problem is: vertically scrolling works fine, but horizontal scrolling does NOT work at all. I already tested various combinations of `MATCH_PARENT`, `WRAP_CONTENT` and `FILL_PARENT`. No try even worked close. So my question is: What am I missing here?

> Here is the code:

```
public class PlayerView extends View {

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private int player_loop;
    private int player_count;

    public PlayerView(Context context, int player_count){
        super(context);
        setPlayer_count(player_count);
    }

    public ScrollView create_scrollView(){

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getContext());
        ScrollView.LayoutParams scroll_params = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
                ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(scroll_params);
        scrollView.addView(create_relativeLayout());

        return scrollView;
    }

    public RelativeLayout create_relativeLayout(){

        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        create_Player_Table_Layout();

        return relativeLayout;
    }

    public void create_Player_Table_Layout(){

        for(player_loop = 1; player_loop <= player_count; player_loop++){

            relativeLayout.addView(player_table(getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_player_name) + player_loop, player_loop));

        }
    }

    public TableLayout player_table(String playername, int playernumber){

        tableLayout = new TableLayout(getContext());
        tableLayout.setId(playernumber * 1000);

        if (playernumber > 1) {

            //TABLE PLACEMENT
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tbl_params_New = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tbl_params_New.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (playernumber - 1) * 1000);
            tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tbl_params_New);
        }

        //Add Playername
        TableRow row_playername = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView view_name = new TextView(getContext());

        TableRow.LayoutParams view_name_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        view_name_params.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

        view_name.setLayoutParams(view_name_params);
        view_name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view_name.setText(playername);
        view_name.setTextSize(20);
        view_name.setId(playernumber * 100);

        row_playername.addView(view_name);
        tableLayout.addView(row_playername);

        //Add Lifepoints
        TableRow row_lifepoints = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView view_lifepoints = new TextView(getContext());

        TableRow.LayoutParams view_lifepoints_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        view_lifepoints_params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 20);

        view_lifepoints.setText("40");
        view_lifepoints.setTextSize(40);
        view_lifepoints.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view_lifepoints.setId(playernumber * 100 + 10);
        view_lifepoints.setLayoutParams(view_lifepoints_params);
        row_lifepoints.addView(view_lifepoints);
        tableLayout.addView(row_lifepoints);

        Log.d("Test", "Player count:" + player_count);
        for(int opponent_loop = 1; opponent_loop <= player_count; opponent_loop++){
            tableLayout.addView(commander_damage_from_player(player_loop, opponent_loop));
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }

    private TableRow commander_damage_from_player(int player_loop, int opponent_loop){

        TableRow row = new TableRow(getContext());

        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());

        TableRow.LayoutParams layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(20, 0, 40, 20);
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        textView.setText("0 | " + getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_player_name)+ " " + opponent_loop);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setId(player_loop + 100 + opponent_loop);
        row.addView(textView);

        return row;
    }

    private void setPlayer_count(int player_count){
        this.player_count = player_count;
    }

}
```

> And for documentation the calling class:

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        PlayerView playerView = new PlayerView(this, 8);
        setContentView(playerView.create_scrollView());

    }
}
```

Comment: "What am I missing here?" – Nothing. `ScrollView` only scrolls vertically.

Comment: It sounds like a `RecyclerView` may be better suited to your needs since you can scroll in both directions.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the hint! I'll consider it further. For a quick solution I'll go with the nesting an additional horizontal scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do this is by creating a horizontalscrollview to be the child of the scrollview. If you make the minor modification to your create_relativeLayout() to create a horizontalscroll view then it will work correctly. I have seen this happen in other examples.

```
public  HorizontalScrollView create_relativeLayout(){

    HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(getContext());

    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
    create_Player_Table_Layout();
    horizontalScrollView.addView(relativeLayout);
    return horizontalScrollView;
}
```